# Section of a holomorphic vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I am stuck on this problem. Let $E$ be a holomorphic vector bundle on a complex manifold $M$, and $N$ a complex submanifold of codimension at least two. Prove that every section of $E$ on $M\backslash N$ extends to a section of $E$ over $M$. If $F$ is another holomorphic vector bundle over $M$ that is isomorphic to $E$ over $M\backslash N$, then prove that $F$ is isomorphic to $E$ over $M$.

I appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

**The extension**
As Kevin very aptly said, you should use the following amazing theorem of Hartogs:
 *Every holomorphic function on $M\setminus N$ extends to a holomorphic function defined on all of $M$*.
In other word the restriction morphism of rings   $\mathcal O(M) \to \mathcal O(M  \setminus N)$ is surjective and thus actually an isomorphism .
If now $s\in \Gamma (M\setminus N,E)$ is a  section and $n\in N$ is a point where it is not defined, take a trivializing neighbourhood $U$ of $n$ in $M$ and consider a trivializing isomorphism of vector bundles $\phi:E|U\to U\times \mathbb C^r$. Then $\phi \circ s$ is a section on $U\setminus N$ of the trivial bundle $U\times \mathbb C^r$, hence must be of the form   $U\setminus N\to U \times   \mathbb C^r: u\mapsto (u, (s_1(u),s_2(u),...,s_r(u)))$ with $s_i\in \mathcal O(U\setminus N)$.
Now each of the $s_i$'s is just a holomorphic function to which Hartogs's theorem applies.
So it can be extended to $\hat s_i\in \mathcal O(U)$, this yields a section $(\hat s_1,\hat s_2,...,\hat s_r)$ defined on the whole of U of the trivial bundle   on U and by applying $\phi^{-1}$ you get a section of $E|U$.
Since this can be done at every $n\in N$, you get the desired  extension of $s$.

**The isomorphism**
You are given  an isomorphism of vector bundles $u:E|(M\setminus N) \to F|(M\setminus N)$.
To reduce to the above, the trick is to consider the holomorphic *vector bundle* $HOM(E,F)$ (note the capital letters in $HOM$ !), whose fiber at $m\in M$ is
$Hom(E_m,F_m)=\mathcal L (E_m,F_m)$, the linear maps between two good old vector spaces.
You can then consider that $u\in \Gamma(M\setminus N, HOM(E,F))$ and extend that section  holomorphically to $\Gamma(M, HOM(E,F))$, obtaining a morphism defined on all of $M$ of our bundles $\hat u:E\to F$.
End of story? No! You must show that  $\hat u$ is an ISOmorphism also on$N$.
Here the trick is to look at the induced morphism on maximal exterior powers $\Lambda ^r \hat u:\Lambda ^r E\to \Lambda ^r F$. It can be considered as a section of a line bundle , namely $s= {\Lambda ^r \hat u} \in \Gamma(M,(\Lambda ^r E)^*\otimes \Lambda ^r F)$.
Now the points where $\hat u$ is not an isomorphism correspond to the points where the section $s$ is zero: this is of codimension one or empty.
But since we know that $u$ is an isomorphism outside of $N$, that zero-set must be a subset of $ N$, hence not of codimension one, hence empty.
So $\hat u:E\to F$ is indeed an isomorphism (everywhere!)  of the given bundles.
(All of this second section can also be done by more explicit local calculations which translate the above)

**Caveat**
Hartogs's theorem is false in the real analytic case: the analytic function $\frac {1}{x^2+y^2}$ on $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \lbrace  (0,0) \rbrace$ cannot be extended continuously, let alone analytically, across $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Look up Hartogs's theorem (probably the book of Griffiths-Harris is a good place to look); use the fact that vector bundles are locally trivial.